# Files/directory with root owner in /home

Tags: 14.04, permissions

While look at the /home folder, I found the followings

```
drwx------  2 root        root         4096 mag 29  2013 .gvfs
-rw-r--r--  1 root        root           58 ott 22  2013 .install4j
drwxr-xr-x  2 root        root         4096 ott  1  2013 .rpmdb
-rw-rw-r--  1 tigerjack89 tigerjack89    58 ott 22  2013 .install4j_jre
```

What they are? Can I switch them to my_user:my_group? 
Actually, I don't know if I can safely delete this folder and the previous .install4j file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- .[gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) is a virtual file system for gnome. Leave this as it is; mess with it and your system probably (most likely) will fail to work as intended.
- .install4j is a java installer builder. Can be removed but it will depend on why you installed it and if you still need it.
- .rpmdb is the RPM package database. If you do not use the Redhat package manager then you can remove it. If you do (it is related to the `alien` package) leave it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your time :)
Actually, I've installed both JDK 8 and JDK 7, but I don't think the installer is still needed, am I right?
About rpmdb, I don't think I'm using it. However, looking inside the folder, there are various __db files. There is any program which depends on it?

Comment: Quoting [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2256823&p=13187660#post13187660) reply from schragge 

As to the .rpmdb directory, see discussion on [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1069350): . It gets created as a side-effect when calling old versions of dkms (before trusty, I believe) while installing any dkms-based kernel modules like NVIDIA/AMD proprietary video drivers or VirtualBox. It can be safely removed.